# set different location for source and destination workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that allows me to copy data from one workbook to another when a criteria is met.
It works fine when the source and destination workbook have the same location but it doesn't work when the source workbook is located on a different drive than the destination workbook. How can I modify my code to make it work?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Sub exportData()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim erow As Integer
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Date1, Name, Total_Time
   
    
    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = SourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Allan Border Labour Hours.xlsm")
    Set DestSheet = wbk.Sheets("Labour")
    

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Allan Border" Then
            Date1 = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            Name = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
            Total_Time = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
            

            erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

          
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Value = Date1
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 2).Value = Name
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 3).Value = Total_Time
            
            
        End If
    Next i

    wbk.Save
    wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Allan Border Labour Hours.xlsm")` with `Workbooks.Open("full path of Allan Border Labour Hours.xlsm")`. Example: `Workbooks.Open("D:/NewFolder/Allan Border Labour Hours.xlsm")`

Comment: Thanks Raymond, would this work if the file is located on OneDrive? Example: Workbooks.Open ("https\\....")

Comment: Why not give it a try? I don't see why not though.